# Why my code show a false value of char variable

Tags: c, validation, input

I write my code in **C** language but when I write like this

```
int main() 
{ 
   char one,two,three;
   int num=0;
   scanf("%d",&num);
   scanf("%c %c %c",&one,&two,&three);
   printf("%c %c %c",one,two,three);
}
```

When I input chars `a b c` that shows me

```
 a b
```

and does not show `c`

It happens when I input `num`. If I set a variable of `num` to be `3` it shows me

```
a b c
```

like my input

How to solve this?

Comment: when dealing with keyboard i/o you are better off using fgets() and then sscanf()

Comment: %d stops on non-digit and leaves it in the buffer.  Use fgets  to read a whole line and sscanf to try to read num, but check the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your first "**scanf**" processes, in addition to whatever number you're inputting you're also putting a newline character "**/n**" in as well. This is being read by your second "**scanf**" such that **&one** is your new line.

To fix this just change this line:

```
scanf("%c %c %c",&one,&two,&three);
```

To this:

```
scanf(" %c %c %c",&one,&two,&three);
```

The extra space in the second line will prevent the newline from being used by the second "**scanf**" statement.